# Where to host reactjs site on web with a domain and a ssl certificate?

Tags: reactjs, ssl, cloud, hosting

I have a react website and want to deploy it to the web. I already bought a domain on godaddy and want to link it to the site. I also want to have a ssl certificate for it.

What is the easiest way to do this. I already tried out heroku but i had trouble linking godaddy to heroku and getting a ssl certificate. I would be ok paying 5-10 bucks per month

Thanks!

Comment: Let's Encrypt X.509 certificates are free...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Check [now.sh](https://zeit.co/now), it is the simplest way I've seen.**

   They give you ssl cert, and if you need you can use your own domain name.

   You will be able to build your site using npm/yarn:

   In package.json:

   ```
   "scripts": {
     "start": "react-scripts start",
     "build": "react-scripts build && now build/ --public
     .....  
   }
   ```

   Then from root of your project run

   ```
   yarn build
   ```
2. **Buy VPS and setup all things manually.**

   It is not so hard, you will need:

   - Buy vps/vds, for example on [digitalocean.com](https://digitalocean.com)
   - Install node+npm/yarn, apache/nginx, setup ssl certs using letsencrypt (usually it takes me 30 min to configure new server)

Second case is cheaper and gives you much more flexibility but will take more time and effort.

Comment: thanks for the response, do you have a guide on how to set up the vps?

Comment: @JulianBeck, [initial setup instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: @JulianBeck, here is full guide how deploy react app on vps: [Deploying create-react-app with Nginx and Ubuntu](https://medium.com/@timmykko/deploying-create-react-app-with-nginx-and-ubuntu-e6fe83c5e9e7)

Comment: Thank you, i just got it working with a ssl certificate and a react app. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you'd be a okay with http and free hosting with domain ending in 'surge.sh', you can check out 
**surge.sh**

It's easy to use. Setup once on your machine, create a build with yarn/npm. Run surge command and provide you build path. 
You could also give a custom domain name.
This is the easiest way if you want to host a informative website with no use auth.
(I've a bunch of websites hosted on it, created while learning reactjs - http://moview.surge.sh or http://readers-digest.surge.sh)